# Grouping results from MySQL query according to one column of table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, while-loop

I have the following query:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Date, Due, Paid from patient_sessions WHERE Name=? AND Invoiced=? AND Type=? AND SUBSTR(Date,1,7)=? ORDER BY Date")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$client,$invoiced,$type,$month);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($date,$due,$paid);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

RUN SOMETHING HERE

}
```

Rather than use `while ($stmt->fetch())`, which loops through all of the rows returned, I would like to group the rows returned by the value in the Due column, and then loop through each row per group, but I am not sure how to do this.

**EXTRA INFO**

I would like to return the results in the following format:

One line for each 'Due' value returned with a count of the number of rows for each value (this is what the grouping is needed for).

And then...

One line for each row, ordered by date where all of the 3 values (Date,Due,Paid) are displayed.

I am stuck because I need the grouping and also the individual rows.  Can I return both with the one query?

Comment: What do you want to do for each value in the columns `Date` and `paid` for each group in `due`?

Comment: First I want to display a count of the number of rows in each group.  Then I want to display a separate line for each row where the date and the amount due and any payment are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT Date, Due, Paid from patient_sessions 
        WHERE Name=? AND Invoiced=? AND Type=? AND SUBSTR(Date,1,7)=? 
        ORDER BY Due, Date";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$client,$invoiced,$type,$month);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($date,$due,$paid);
$data = array();
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    if (!isset($data[$due]))
    {
         $data[$due] = array();
    }
    $data[$due][] = array($date,$paid);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my question to make it clearer regarding the data that I need to return.  Can I achieve both the grouping and the individual rows ordered by date in the same query?

Comment: Yes, I can see that it returns an array grouped by the 'Due' column.  I'm just not sure how to return the data in the dual format that I need it (as per my edited question) and whether this can all be done using the array generated by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 'Group By' and 'Having' clauses.

Will need more information to give you a real answer but hopefully these links will help.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry was a bit rushed at work so thought I would help out a bit. Sounds like the question has changed a bit since it was originally asked, most likely it can be solved with a inner sql query:
select a, b, c, (select count(*) from table_d e where e.c = d.c group by c) from table_d d order by b desc.

Or just run the two queries seperatly but you will have to lock the tables to make sure no additional data goes in between the queries.